# Windows Nanoserver container fails in GitLab als Image, "The system cannot find the file specified.: unknown"

Tags: visual-c++, gitlab, containers, gitlab-ci-runner, windows-container

I am trying to minimize the size of my Windows Container based build environment. I run it in GitLab like this:

```
build windows:
  image: 
    name: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-ltsc2022
    pull_policy: always
  stage: build
  tags:
    - windows
  script:
    - pwsh.exe --version
```

But the start up fails with:

> WARNING: Event retrieved from the cluster: Error: failed to start containerd task "build": hcs::System::CreateProcess build: The system cannot find the file specified.: unknown 
> ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: setting up trapping scripts on emptyDir: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("build"). Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information

My goal is to create a Visual C++ based build container to build a Windows application. Windows Core is pretty big, so I wanted to test if nanoserver might work.

Is there a way to start it?

Comment: Have you tried the Server Core image to see if there's a similar error? Also, have you tried the 2019 version?

Comment: No, not yet. But I had an idea: as far as I know Gitlab defines in a config what shell to spawn. The configuration starts powershell.exe which is not available in nanoserver. Our admin is currently on vacation so I am not sure if my assumption is correct.

Comment: That is correct, PowerShell is not available on the Nano Server base image. I believe that's the reason you have the PS one on your spec above. If GitLab is using the generic base image for something else and trying to spin up PowerShell, then that might be a reason. I tried to run a Nano Server base image locally and called PowerShell and the error is the same as yours.

Comment: So, I just ran some more testing. When trying to call the mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-ltsc2022 image as usual via docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-ltsc2022 powershell, it fails with the same error. I looked at the dockerfile for the image here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docker/blob/master/release/7-2/nanoserver2022/docker/Dockerfile, and noticed the executable is registered as "pwsh.exe", so I ran: docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-nanoserver-ltsc2022 pwsh.exe and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for testing. I also tried that out, but as you said the executable is called pwsh. I added it to my entrypoint which seems to be ignored by GitLab. So my assumption is, that GitLab will just call what is configured in the Runner config for this machine. It always seem to call powershell.exe. If that is the case, I may need to find a way to change that. Thank you for your comments.